# JSON class mapping in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an external API that when I deserialise using json2csharp gives me class names that are the same for different API calls. The contents are not the same, but have the same names.

If I rename the classes and attempt to deserialise the base class, part of the JSON from the service will deserialise, but not for the classes that are renamed (as I would expect).

Is there a JSON property that I can use that maps one class name to the name the JSON object expects? I'm using Newtonsoft.

Comment: There is no problem with renamed classes as long as you rename them at all places so the same class will be used. JSON did not expect a special class name, just the structure. The class name does not matter at all

Comment: @SirRufo True, unless [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) is set in the serializer settings.

Comment: @SirRufo - thanks :)